# Change YouTube iFrame source on select change in WP

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe

Inside a WP template I am loading a YouTube play list via iFrame. I have a select box above it that allows users to select another playlist. It seems simple, but I keep running into browser security issues.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#channelChooser').change(function() {
    $(this).next('iframe').attr('src', this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="channelChooser" id="channelChooser">
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/playlistlist=one">One</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=Two">Two</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=Three">Three</option>
</select>
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=One&listType=playlist" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I get this error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=Two' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I just want to be able to change the youtube play list on select, preferably without a plug in because this should be simple. Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to work here, although youtube does say "invalid parameters"...

Comment: I didn't leave the actual play lists in there, but I have real ones in my code. Not sure why the first one loads fine, but changing it triggers a browser security warning in Chrome

Comment: I see. Yes, I can reproduce the issue with a real playlist URL.

Comment: Probably you are using wrong URL for playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X-Frame-Options: Sameorigin` is used by YouTube to prevent [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking).  You will need to embed the actual playlist.

[Embed videos & playlists](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en)

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link!

Comment: Thanks! The formatting of the embed link was wrong. Found the link you suggested and it works as expected! Much appreciated.